# Specify on which host (rank) to spawn MPI processes

Tags: python, mpi, spawn

I have some sort of multi-agent system using MPI. I start the main actors with `mpiexec -np 1 Admin.py : -np 4 Other.py`. Each "other.py" also spawns one more process. For computational efficiency I would really like to have the spawned processes on the same processor (rank) as the parent. How can I achieve this? (And for curiosity: 1. Where are they spawned by default? 2. Is there a way to see where the processes run?)

My code for Other.py contains the following (no MWE)

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD                  
rank = comm.Get_rank() 
...
icomm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,args["front_process.py",str(rank)],\
 maxprocs=1)
```

By providing and info argument to Spawn you can normally control where to put the spawned process.

```
myinfo = MPI.Info.Create()
myinfo.Set("host","%s" % str(rank) )
icomm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,args=["front_process.py",str(rank)],\
 maxprocs=1,info=myinfo)
```

However, when adding this "info", MPI crashes: `All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled.`

Answer (score 0):

New processes are spawned in accordance with the slots defined in the provided hostlist (or on the local host if no hostlist is provided) and the allocation rules (usually supplied as arguments to `mpiexec`). If your MPI job runs under the supervision of a resource manager (RM), e.g. SGE, LSF, etc.,  and if the MPI library is tightly integrated with the RM, then the hostlist and the available slots are fixed by the RM and the `host` key in the `MPI_Info` object serves as a filter to the RM-specified list (at least true for Open MPI).

If not using a RM, you should probably supply a hostlist with enough slots defined for each host. With Open MPI 1.6.x it is possible to add new hosts to the list with the `add-host` key. If running under a RM, you should make the appropriate request (this is site-specific).

To find out where your processes run, use `MPI.Get_processor_name()`. On most cluster systems it returns the hostname of the node where the calling process executes.

Comment: Currently only testing on a multicore system with one processors. But I am still wondering why the code crashes when specifying the info (`All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled`) but not when I don't provide the info. All processors should be occupied (`mpiexec -n 2 code.py` and 4 spawned processes)